# Does a way to make the command prompt of os.system not show up at all

Tags: python, windows, command-prompt, os.system

I'm trying to use os.system to run some command lines in a python module that would run a different file. While i know that subprocess exist I am unable to use it for various reasons, therefore I would like to know if a method to prevent the command prompt from showing up  when using os.system exists. I have also tried using .pyw instead of .py, the command prompt still shows up regardless.

The closest thing i could find was 
os.system(code >/dev/null) 
however it prevented my code from running totally for some reason and thus can not be used.

Current code:

```
import ctypes

kernel32 = ctypes.WinDLL('kernel32')
user32 = ctypes.WinDLL('user32')

SW_HIDE = 0

hWnd = kernel32.GetConsoleWindow()
if hWnd:
    user32.ShowWindow(hWnd, SW_HIDE)

asset_list = ('code.py')
os.system('python '+asset_list)
```

this causes the command prompt to flash each time os.system is called.

I expected the command prompt to not show up however being able to reduce it from being staying open till the code is done running to a flash is a great improvement, sadly it is not enough, i require the command prompt to not be visible at all.

Help would be greatly appreciated as most of the search online comes back to using subprocess.

Comment: Use the `subprocess` module instead of `os.system` — it gives you a lot more control.

Comment: yes, i have read alot about it, however I am unable to use it and am wondering if there is a different solution @martineau

Comment: Seems strange that you can run `os.system` but not use `subprocess`... Anyway, you ccould create a shortcut to a batch file that executes the command, and then change the properties of the shortcut to make it run minimized.

Comment: The console is flashing because you don't have one, so `kernel32.GetConsoleWindow()` returns 0. (It should be `None`; you have to set `kernel32.GetConsoleWindow.restype = ctypes.c_void_p` for handles.) To allocate a console, call `kernel32.AllocConsole()`. Then hide the window. Console programs by default will inherit this hidden console, unless you use CMD's built-in `start` command -- or unless you pass `creationflags=subprocess.CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE` with `subprocess.Popen`.

Answer (score 0):

After poking around somemore I realised I can indeed use subprocess and am able to get rid of the command prompt, my bad and thank you for the replies!

Answer (score 0):

After some digging, the ultimate clear solution:

```html
kernel32 = ctypes.WinDLL('kernel32')
user32 = ctypes.WinDLL('user32')

kernel32.GetConsoleWindow.restype = ctypes.c_void_p
kernel32.AllocConsole()
console = kernel32.GetConsoleWindow()
user32.ShowWindow(console, 0)
```